# MongoDB, mongoose - data returned from GET request does not match schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoDB and mongoose.  I'm trying to write my first api.  Here is what my schema looks like:

```
var movementSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    difficulty: String,
    joints: Array
});
```

And here is what my post request looks like:

```
.post(function(req, res) {

    var movement = new Movement({
        name: req.body.name,
        difficulty: req.body.difficulty,
        joints: req.body.joints
    });


    // save the movement and check for errors
    movement.save(function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Movement created!' });
    });
})
```

However it looks like my request object is empty and what is returned from the server on a GET looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "56f963f699d121ec35bbe91f",
    "__v": 0,
    "joints": []
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The parsed result in `req.body.joints` will not actually be an "array". Chances are it's a "string", and that's probably because the "POST" request has not formed the data correctly, or probably the wrong request type in headers. Check how you are sending the data and the serialization of the "array". When all is reasonably "sane" ( and you actually have an array )  then `Movement.create(req.body,function(err) { .. })` should be all you need.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've got other records in your `Movement` collection that do not match the schema you've defined in Mongoose. Either you'll need to remove those records from the collection that don't match the schema or change the Schema to not be strict.

> #### [Schema Option Strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict)
>
> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

```
var movementSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    difficulty: String,
    joints: Array
}, { strict: false} );
```

---

#### Edit for Empty Request Body

There are two things to look for when getting an empty request body in Express.

1. Make sure that `bodyParser.json()` was registered with Express so `req.body` on JSON requests are properly parsed.
2. Make sure that when requesting your service you've set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`

Comment: I dropped my mongo DB and created one new record after implementing "strict: false" but it still isn't working.

Comment: You are connected to your mongo instance and you've specified the DB to connect to? How did you create the record? Using Mongoose or through the Shell?

Comment: I am connected to mongo and used Mongoose to create the record.

Comment: So after rereading your question, I see that you said the `req.body` is empty. Are you using `express`? If so, make sure that you've added the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware to your app. Without `app.use(bodyParser.json());` in your app, you won't be able to use `req.body` for accessing JSON request bodies.

Comment: Thanks - I am using bodyParser :(

Comment: When you're making the request to the route to create a new `Movement` are you sending over the `Content-Type` header as `application/json`? If not, even though you're using `body-parser` your `req.body` will remain undefined.

Comment: This was the issue - I didn't have headers set correctly in postman

Comment: @OliverBradley Updated my answer based on comments

Comment: `{ "strict": false }` is not the answer here, since it would likely store as a "string" and not an array. The problem will be in the request. And that's now confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

In case of empty ***req.body***, make sure body-parser is used. It should be used before routing.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

*body-parser used and then using routing.*

```
app.use('/api',api);
```